# Removing "None" from the output. Print hexadecimal digits from 0-F

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, hex

```
def hex_numb(a): # to print or create a string of hex numbers frm 0-F
```

> ```
>    for a in range (a,16):
>     b=hex(a)
>     b=b[2]
>     b=b.upper()
>     a+=1
>     print b
> ```

## Returns 0-F all 16 digits and None after F

Comment: -1: Looks like homework

Comment: need to remove "none" to use this function as a recursion for almost 80 more digits..

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments:

1. Why is there an argument (`a`) to this function? If you always want `0`-`F`, remove the argument, and if you want to specify the value to be returned lose the `for` loop.
2. When using a `for x in range(n)` loop, you don't need to manually increment `x` (i.e. `x += 1`) inside the loop.
3. Your various string manipulations can be done in one go: `b = hex(a)[2].upper()`.
4. Your function is returning `None` implicitly (standard Python behaviour when your function doesn't explicitly `return`), so if you `print hex_numb(0)` you run the function, printing all the values, then `print` the return value, `None`. All of the printing work is done inside the function, just call it: `hex_numb(0)`.

Comment: Hi Jonrsharpe, what i want to do is, i will call the function which will return me hex values from 0-F only. it will start giving values from the value i give in function calling. and after it returns the value from the function till 'F', i will do another task. I want to start from 00 to 0F then increment 1 and start from 10-1F then 20 to 2F then so on.

Comment: In that case, I suggest returning a list: `return [hex(x)[2].upper() for x in range(a, 16)]`